# How to calculate the potential of a photocell?

Tags: photoelectric-effect, solar-cells

[image]

My guess is that because the wire is connected to a single point on the plate, we can treat it as a point charge and use the formula: $$V = k\frac{k(\pm q)}{|r|}$$

But I think there are different situation. One is when a wire is connected the other when a wire is not.

When the wire is connected, there is really no accumulated charge on the plates, so I guess the formula doesn't work. So I don't know which formula to use, or what the formula is. I guess what matters is the KE of the ejected electron. If we increase the frequency of the coming photon above the threshold frequency, the potential will logically increase.

Comment: pl.see the discussion-https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/333101/why-does-resistance-increase-with-potential-at-collector-in-the-photoelectric-ef?rq=1 which may help in defining potential difference

Answer (score -1):

The voltage across the photodiode is the same as the voltage of the power supply (they are in parallel).

Put voltage of the power supply into the Shockley Diode equation to calculate the current through the ammeter if the current generated by exposure to light is $I_\mathrm{L}$,

$$
I=I_\mathrm{S} \left( e^{V_\mathrm{D}/(n V_\mathrm{T})}-1 \right) - I_\mathrm{L}
$$

Comment: That equation is for a semiconductor junction diode.

Comment: @Pieter yes, it is the simplest model of a photodiode (but notice the additional term to due to light generation $I_L$) . Downvote seems a bit harsh.

Comment: The question is about a _vacuum_ photo cell.

Comment: Oh, I stand corrected.