# What increases the resistance at collector in photoelectric effect?

Tags: electrical-resistance, photoelectric-effect

The photoelectric experiment uses a setup like this:

[image: https://dc.edu.au/wp-content/uploads/1.png]

The graph of photoelectric current $I$ against potential applied at the anode/collecting plate $V$ looks something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R17EJ.png]

Once we reach the saturation current, further increasing the collector potential $V$ does **not** further increase the photoelectric current $I$. Rather, resistance simply increases ($R = \frac{V}{I}$). But what is the underlying *physical* change in the electrodes that increases the resistance as $V$ increases? Are there more negative charges on the cathode, inhibiting the current? Is that the reason why an increasing potential $V$ causes $R$ to increase?

Comment: How can voltage get "collected"? Charges may collect, resulting in a **potential difference** between two points.

Comment: Just write "increase in collector potential". Please also don't write irrelevant things like "thanks to electric attraction". I've edited, and submitted for review. Please see. You must have got a notification.

Comment: rest is fine to me.